# Why are subdomains not working?

Tags: domain, subdomain

This is probably a stupid question but for some reason I cannot create subdomains

`anything.mydomain.com` doesn't work

but `www.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com` work perfectly..

I've assigned them in my webserver configuration files (lighttpd.conf), but I was wondering if I need to configure them with the domain provider instead.

where is the issue here ?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create DNS records for the subdomains and point them to your server. If you want all subdomains to point to your server then a [wildcard DNS record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) is probably best.

If however, you want specific subdomains to point to your server then [CNAME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) records are probably the way to go.

You will need to make these changes on your hosts nameservers.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure them on Domain provider or on dns configuration add an CNAME entry for * to go to same ip.

At host name add * , CNAME type and address should be ip of the server.

Answer (score 1):

What does "doesn't work" mean? What kind of error you get from where? If it's your browser telling you it can't find `anything.mydomain.com`, than you have to edit your domain entries in the DNS accordingly, so your "domain provider" would be the target to solve this.